Dependency Conflict in Angular 10 Project After Adding New Library: Unable to Resolve Dependency Tree
I have an Angular 10 project(chrome extension) that was working perfectly until I recently added a new library to integrate additional functionality. After installing the new library, I started encountering dependency conflicts, making it impossible to build my project.
Here’s my setup:
Angular Version: 10.2.1
Previously Installed Packages:
@angular/core: ^10.2.4
@angular/common: ^10.2.4
Other Angular dependencies aligned with version 10.
Node Version: v16.14.0
NPM Version: 8.3.1
when i am trying to build my project using gulp command. i am getting following error. basically these are typescript related error and when i installed new version using following command
npm install --save-dev @types/chrome
the typescript related problem is getting resolved but there is another issue arising with the package dependency
src$ gulp
[12:35:42] Using gulpfile ~/extensionFnx/Clodura-Extension-5.0/src/gulpfile.js
[12:35:42] Starting 'default'...
[12:35:42] Starting 'ng-build'...
running... ../node_modules/.bin/ng build

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-window-token : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar/smooth-scroll : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @auth0/angular-jwt : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-toastr : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-avatar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-select/ng-select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
(node:76404) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/pravinmohite/extensionFnx/Clodura-Extension-5.0/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

ERROR in app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:31:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.
  Type 'string[]' provides no match for the signature '(items: { [key: string]: any; }): void'.

31     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:31:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

31     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                            ~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:151:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

151       chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                    ~~~~~~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:151:44 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

151       chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                               ~~~~
app/login/login.component.ts:63:37 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

63           chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                       ~~~~~~~~~
app/login/login.component.ts:63:48 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

63           chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                                  ~~~~
app/app.module.ts:41:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

41     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~
app/app.module.ts:41:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

41     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                            ~~~~
background-script/background.ts:166:8 - error TS2339: Property 'action' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.

166 chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
           ~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:311:16 - error TS2339: Property 'scripting' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.

311         chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                   ~~~~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:388:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

388     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:388:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

388     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                             ~~~~


[12:36:07] 'ng-build' errored after 26 s
[12:36:07] Error: Command failed: ../node_modules/.bin/ng build
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-window-token : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar/smooth-scroll : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @auth0/angular-jwt : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-toastr : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-scrollbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-avatar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @ng-select/ng-select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling ngx-clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
(node:76404) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /home/pravinmohite/extensionFnx/Clodura-Extension-5.0/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

ERROR in app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:31:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.
  Type 'string[]' provides no match for the signature '(items: { [key: string]: any; }): void'.

31     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:31:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

31     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                            ~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:151:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

151       chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                    ~~~~~~~~~
app/services/auth/auth.service.ts:151:44 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

151       chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                               ~~~~
app/login/login.component.ts:63:37 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

63           chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                       ~~~~~~~~~
app/login/login.component.ts:63:48 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

63           chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                                  ~~~~
app/app.module.ts:41:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

41     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                 ~~~~~~~~~
app/app.module.ts:41:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

41     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                            ~~~~
background-script/background.ts:166:8 - error TS2339: Property 'action' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.

166 chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
           ~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:311:16 - error TS2339: Property 'scripting' does not exist on type 'typeof chrome'.

311         chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                   ~~~~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:388:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(items: { [key: string]: any; }) => void'.

388     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~
background-script/background.ts:388:42 - error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.

388     chrome.storage?.local.get(["token"]).then((result) => {
                                             ~~~~


    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:537:15)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    at Process.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)


I have Tried
Removed the new library:
npm uninstall pocketbase
Attempted to reinstall dependencies:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
Downgraded conflicting dependencies:
Removed @auth0/angular-jwt and installed version 4.0.0, which is compatible with Angular 10.
Verified the versions of all Angular packages and ensured they are aligned to 10.2.4:
npm install @angular/animations@10.2.4 @angular/common@10.2.4 @angular/compiler@10.2.4 @angular/core@10.2.4 --save-exact
Cleared the NPM cache and retried:
npm cache clean --force
npm install
Current Issues
Despite these efforts, I still face dependency resolution issues or other errors when running npm install or attempting to build the project with ng build.
Goal
I want to restore my project to its previous working state without introducing new libraries or upgrading Angular to a newer version.
package.json file
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.4",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.127",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "ng": "^0.0.0",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.1",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^7.5.4",
    "ngx-spinner": "^11.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.54.4",
    "tsify": "~5.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.15",
    "@types/yargs": "^16.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.44.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  }

